# Wrong results for group by in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
names1880 = pd.read_csv('test.txt', names=['name', 'sex', 'births'])
names1880.groupby('sex').births.sum()
```

A sample file for the year 1880 (us baby names) is used. The expected result is something like this...

```
F 90993
M 110493
Name: births
```

But I am getting random total for each row.

```
0     58385
1     35818
2     33920
...
1896    57
1897    57
1898    57
```

How do I get correct results for male and female?

**update**: 
The following code seems to be working as expected. Does it mean that I have to break the object and can not use as a method?

```
mygroup=names1880.groupby('sex')
mygroup['births'].sum()
```

Here are the first 10 lines from test.txt file

```
Mary,F,7065
Anna,F,2604
Emma,F,2003
Elizabeth,F,1939
Minnie,F,1746
Margaret,F,1578
Ida,F,1472
Alice,F,1414
Bertha,F,1320
Sarah,F,1288
```

I am using pandas version 0.7.0 if that matters.

Comment: The code you posted would work as desired if the dataframe is getting loaded properly. Please post a few lines of `test.txt`.

Comment: 0.7.0 is VERY old. Its possible that the ``getattr`` accessor (e.g. the dot was not implemented back then (or didn't work correctly, etc)). You should for sure upgrade.

Comment: Yes. This was version issue. How old is this 0.7 version? I was not able to upgrade initially because the memory (VM) was too low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote works well.
When I copy the data sample you gave :

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', header = None, 
                             names = ['name', 'sex', 'births'])

data.groupby('sex').births.sum()
```

It prints :

```
sex
F      22429
```

You don't have to break anything, but you always can ! (maybe your issue is because of your Pandas version that is too old.)

When I add some men:

```
Mary,F,7065
Anna,F,2604
Emma,F,2003
Elizabeth,F,1939
Minnie,F,1746
Margaret,F,1578
Ida,F,1472
Jeremy,M,1477
Alice,F,1414
Bertha,F,1320
Sarah,F,1288
Jonathan,M,1255
```

Here what it prints, as expected :

```
sex
F      22429
M       2732
Name: births, dtype: int64
```